# counting results of complex query

Tags: mysql

The query below outputs this results:

```
+------------+------------+
| testID     | testStatus|
+------------+------------+
|          1 | PASS       |
|          2 | PASS       |
|          3 | SKIP       |
|          4 | PASS       |
+------------+------------+
```

How can I change the query to give me the PASS Count, SKIP Count, FAIL Count and PASS %, SKIP %, FAIL %

```
    SELECT orsm.testID, orsm.testStatus
    FROM mdro orsm, mdr mr, cmt cm,
    mmrprt mrt, mmtt mtt, mmuq mui, mmgt mgt, mmft mft
    WHERE mr.cmtID = cm.ID 
    AND orsm.ParentID = mr.ID 
    AND cm.IdentID = mui.ID 
    AND cm.DEVID = 2 
    AND cm.TestoID = mrt.ID 
    AND cm.SterID = mtt.ID 
    AND cm.FDID = mft.ID 
    AND cm.GID = mgt.ID 
    AND mui.ID="2" 
    AND mrt.Name="cameron" 
    AND mtt.Name="synthesis" 
    AND mft.Name="dupocdna" 
    AND mgt.Name="cce"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this should work, unless I'm misunderstanding something:

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(orsm.testStatus="PASS",1,0)) as pass_count,
SUM(IF(orsm.testStatus="SKIP",1,0)) as skip_count,
SUM(IF(orsm.testStatus="SKIP",1,0)) / COUNT(*) as skip_pct,   
SUM(IF(orsm.testStatus="PASS",1,0)) / COUNT(*) as pass_pct,
SUM(IF(orsm.testStatus="FAIL",1,0)) / COUNT(*) as fail_pct

FROM mdro orsm, mdr mr, cmt cm,
mmrprt mrt, mmtt mtt, mmuq mui, mmgt mgt, mmft mft
WHERE mr.cmtID = cm.ID 
AND orsm.ParentID = mr.ID 
AND cm.IdentID = mui.ID 
... ALL THE REST OF YOUR ANDS ...
```

Comment: works great! what does group by 'x' do and also == does not seem to work it throws an error while = works is that normal?

Comment: @user391986 Yes, you should substitute `==` for `=`. This was an honest mistake on the part of matt. I think you should remove the GROUP BY, though, as it isn't doing anything in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I'm editing the answer. You are right on both accounts. I'm used to putting the GROUP BY no matter what, but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can get what you want by using a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT orsm.testStatus, count(orsm.testID)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY orsm.testStatus
```

Besides that, you should really use JOIN instead of a huge WHERE clause with equalities between columns of different tables. This both improves your query performance and its legibility:

```
SELECT orsm.testID, orsm.testStatus
FROM cmt cm
    JOIN mdr mr ON mr.cmtID = cm.ID 
        JOIN mdro orsm ON orsm.ParentID = mr.ID 
    JOIN mmrprt mrt ON mrt.ID = cm.TestoID
    JOIN mmtt mtt ON mtt.ID = cm.SterID
    JOIN mmuq mui ON mui.ID = cm.IdentID
    JOIN mmgt mgt ON mgt.ID = cm.GID
    JOIN mmft mft ON mft.ID = cm.FDID
WHERE
    cm.DEVID = 2 
    AND mui.ID="2" 
    AND mrt.Name="cameron" 
    AND mtt.Name="synthesis" 
    AND mft.Name="dupocdna" 
    AND mgt.Name="cce"
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up for group it works partially but if there's no data I get no column for the other statuses

Answer (score 1):

It gets a bit tricky when you want to also calculate the percentage:

```
SELECT orsm.testStatus, COUNT(*) AS count, COUNT(*) / matches.total * 100 AS percentage
FROM cmt cm
  JOIN mdr mr ON mr.cmtID = cm.ID 
  JOIN mdro orsm ON orsm.ParentID = mr.ID 
  JOIN mmrprt mrt ON mrt.ID = cm.TestoID
  JOIN mmtt mtt ON mtt.ID = cm.SterID
  JOIN mmuq mui ON mui.ID = cm.IdentID
  JOIN mmgt mgt ON mgt.ID = cm.GID,
  JOIN mmft mft ON mft.ID = cm.FDID,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM cmt cm
      JOIN mdr mr ON mr.cmtID = cm.ID 
      JOIN mdro orsm ON orsm.ParentID = mr.ID 
      JOIN mmrprt mrt ON mrt.ID = cm.TestoID
      JOIN mmtt mtt ON mtt.ID = cm.SterID
      JOIN mmuq mui ON mui.ID = cm.IdentID
      JOIN mmgt mgt ON mgt.ID = cm.GID,
      JOIN mmft mft ON mft.ID = cm.FDID,
    WHERE
      cm.DEVID = 2 
      AND mui.ID="2" 
      AND mrt.Name="cameron" 
      AND mtt.Name="synthesis" 
      AND mft.Name="dupocdna" 
      AND mgt.Name="cce"
  ) matches
WHERE
  cm.DEVID = 2 
  AND mui.ID="2" 
  AND mrt.Name="cameron" 
  AND mtt.Name="synthesis" 
  AND mft.Name="dupocdna" 
  AND mgt.Name="cce"
```